# Subtracting column in dataframe in R. e.g. A-B=corrected A. These are abstract values in sensors seeking correction from dataframeB

Tags: android, mysql, r, date, datetime

Dataframe A

```
Timestamp     Sen1N0        Sen2N0         Sen3N0      Sen4N0
00:00         12            10             30          20
00:05         15            12             11          10
00:10         14            11             13          19
00:15         15            15             13          15
00:20         10            13             11          17
```

data frameB

```
Timestamp     Sen1N4        Sen2N4      Sen3N4      Sen4N4
00:00         9             0             8          0
00:05         1             2             1          1
00:10         8             1             4          9
00:15         12            5             6          5
00:20         1             3             9          7
```

Data frameC = corrected data frameA (Original data frameA- Original data frameB)

corrected data frameA

```
Timestamp     Sen1N0        Sen2N0      Sen3N0      Sen4N0
00:00         3             10             22          20
00:05         14            10             10          9
00:10         6             10             9           10
00:15         12            10             7           10
00:20         9             10             2           10
```

Comment: I guess there is some typo for 'Sen1N0' i.e 4th  element in corrected A.  Shouldn't it be 3 ?

Comment: Apologies - you are right. its should be 3. points out the importance of R rather than manual subtraction. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JOIN` based on timestamp and substract values:

```
SELECT da.Timestamp, 
      da.Sen1N0 - db.Sen1N4 AS Sen1N0,
      da.Sen2N0 - db.Sen2N4 AS Sen2N0,
      da.Sen3N0 - db.Sen3N4 AS Sen3N0,
      da.Sen4N0 - db.Sen4N4 AS Sen4N0
FROM DataframeA da
JOIN dataframeB db
  ON da.Timestamp = db.Timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 'Timestamp' is in the same order in 'A' and 'B' datasets, we substract the columns in 'A' and 'B' except the first column and update it on the 'A' dataset.

```
A[-1] <- A[-1]-B[-1]
A
#  Timestamp Sen1N0 Sen2N0 Sen3N0 Sen4N0
#1     00:00      3     10     22     20
#2     00:05     14     10     10      9
#3     00:10      6     10      9     10
#4     00:15      3     10      7     10
#5     00:20      9     10      2     10
```